# Laravel 5 scope only returns one result

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

I have an App bulit using Laravel 5 with a scope configured to get a list of results but it only returns one result when invoked.

Code:

```
public function scopeBookingDate($query, $date)
{
    return $query->where('booking_date', "LIKE", $date . "%");
}
```

Invoked like this:

```
$bookings = Booking::bookingDate($date)->get();
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Are you sure you have multiple records that start with that date?

Comment: I am sure. When I perform a query in the MySQL console it returns two records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable Query log and let's see what your code is generating. it can be helpful:

```
\DB::enableQueryLog();
$bookings = Booking::bookingDate($date)->get();
\DB::getQueryLog();
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. It appeared that I had formatted my `$date` variable incorrectly.